# How to send JavaFX TextArea through socket?

Tags: sockets, serialization, javafx, tcp, objectoutputstream

I try to make simple text editor on client - server, that let edit few people the same text (sth. like google docs). And now I've got a little problem. I try to send `textarea` through the socket to server and server should send it to all clients, but `textarea` isn't serializable so I can't send it through the `ObjectOutputStream`. Any ideas how to solve this problem? I was looking everywhere for answer but can't find anything.

Comment: Why do you want to send the control itself rather than sending only the text it contains?

Comment: There are many problems when I try to send formatted text, e.g bold or italic or with other Font, and it doens't work well

Comment: `TextArea` doesn't support formatted text. Even if you change its font or css style it will apply to the whole text, and not a part of it, which makes it unsuitable for a text editor purposes.

Comment: Thats right. I have a problem, that I couldn't change a part of the text but I left it for that moment. So should I change TextArea or there is another solve for this problem ?

Comment: You could use [HTMLEditor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) and then just send the underlying html text.

Comment: Oh nice, Thank you Brian. This is really helpful. I will try with this HTML Editor